# Strange environment behavior in parallel plyr

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr

Recently, I have created an object `factor=1` in my workspace, not knowing that there is a function `factor` in the `base` package.

What I intended to do was to use the variable `factor` within a parallel loop, e.g.,

```
library(plyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

workers <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(workers,cores=2)

factor=1

llply(
  as.list(1:2),
  function(x) factor*x,
  .parallel = TRUE,
  .paropts=list(.export=c("factor"))
     )
```

This, however, results in an error that took me so time to understand. As it seems, `plyr` creates the object `factor` in its environemt `exportEnv`, but uses `base::factor` instead of the user provided object. See the following example

```
llply(
  as.list(1:2),
  function(x) {
    function_env=environment();
    global_env=parent.env(function_env);
    export_env=parent.env(global_env);
    list(
      function_env=function_env,
      global_env=global_env,
      export_env=export_env,
      objects_in_exportenv=unlist(ls(envir=export_env)),
      factor_found_in_envs=find("factor"),
      factor_in_exportenv=get("factor",envir=export_env)
      )
    },
  .parallel = TRUE,
  .paropts=list(.export=c("factor"))
  )

stopCluster(workers)
```

If we inspects the output of `llply`, we see that the line `factor_in_exportenv=get("factor",envir=export_env)` does not return `1` (corresponding to the user-provided object) but the function definition of `base::factor`.

Question 1) How can I understand this behavior? I would have expected the output to be `1`.

Question 2) Is there a way to get a warning from `R` if I assign a new value to an object that was already defined in another package (such in my case `factor`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I should note that the error goes away if one uses another variable name that is not used in `base` -- for instance, if we use `a` instead of `factor`. This clearly indicates that `llply` finds `base::factor` (a function) before `factor` (variable with value 1) along its search path. I have tried to replicate this issue with a simplified version of `llply`, i.e.,

```
library(plyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

workers <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(workers,cores=2)

factor=1

llply_simple=function(.x,.fun,.paropts) {
  #give current environment a name
  tmpEnv=environment()
  attr(tmpEnv,"name")="llply_simple_body"
  #print all enclosing envirs of llply_simple_body (see def of allEnv below)
  print(allEnv(tmpEnv))
  cat("------\nResults:\n")
  do.ply=function(i) {
    .fun(i)
  }
  fe_call <- as.call(c(list(quote(foreach::foreach), i = .x), .paropts))
  fe <- eval(fe_call)
  foreach::`%dopar%`(fe, do.ply(i))
}
```

`llply_simple` uses a recursive helper function (`allEnv`) that loops through all enclosing environments. It returns a vector with all environment names

```
allEnv=function(x) {
  if (environmentName(x)=="R_EmptyEnv") {
    return(environmentName(x))
  } else {
    c(environmentName(x),allEnv(parent.env(x)))
  }
}
```

It's interesting that the simplified function actually works as expected (i.e., gives `1` and `2` as results)

```
llply_simple(1:2,function(x) x*factor,list(.export="factor"))
#[1] "llply_simple_body"  "R_GlobalEnv"        "package:doParallel" "package:parallel"  
#[5] "package:iterators"  "package:foreach"    "package:plyr"       "tools:rstudio"     
#[9] "package:stats"      "package:graphics"   "package:grDevices"  "package:utils"     
#[13] "package:datasets"   "package:methods"    "Autoloads"          "base"              
#[17] "R_EmptyEnv"
#--------
#Results:        
#[[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2
```

So the only significant difference of `llply_simple` with respect to the full `plyr::llply` function is that the latter belongs to a package. Let's try to move `llply_simple` into a package.

```
package.skeleton(list=c("llply_simple","allEnv"),name="llplyTest")
unlink("./llplyTest/DESCRIPTION")
devtools::create_description("./llplyTest",
                             extra=list("devtools.desc.author"='"T <t@t.com>"'))
tmp=readLines("./llplyTest/man/llply_simple.Rd")
tmp[which(grepl("\\\\title",tmp))+1]="Test1"
writeLines(tmp,"./llplyTest/man/llply_simple.Rd")
tmp=readLines("./llplyTest/man/allEnv.Rd")
tmp[which(grepl("\\\\title",tmp))+1]="Test2"
writeLines(tmp,"./llplyTest/man/allEnv.Rd")
devtools::install("./llplyTest")
```

And now try to execute `llplyTest::llply_simple` from our new package `llplyTest`

```
library(llplyTest)
llplyTest::llply_simple(1:2,function(x) x*factor,list(.export="factor"))
#[1] "llply_simple_body"  "llplyTest"          "imports:llplyTest"  "base"              
#[5] "R_GlobalEnv"        "package:doParallel" "package:parallel"   "package:iterators" 
#[9] "package:foreach"    "package:plyr"       "tools:rstudio"      "package:stats"     
#[13] "package:graphics"   "package:grDevices"  "package:utils"      "package:datasets"  
#[17] "package:methods"    "Autoloads"          "base"               "R_EmptyEnv"
#------
#Results:
#Error in do.ply(i) : 
#  task 1 failed - "non-numeric argument to binary operator"
```

All of a sudden we get the same error as in my original question from 2013. So the issue is clearly connected to calling the function from a package. Let's have a look at the output of `allEnv`: it basically gives us the sequence of environments that `llpy_simple` and `llplyTest::llpy_simple` use to look for variables that should get exported. Actually it's `foreach` that does the exporting and if one is interested to see why `foreach` really starts with the environment that we named `llply_simple_body`, look at the source code of `foreach::%dopar%`, `foreach:::getDoPar` and `foreach:::.foreachGlobals$fun` and follow the path of the `envir` argument.

We can now clearly see that the non-package version has a different search sequence than `llplyTest::llpy_simple` and that the package-version will find `factor` in `base` first!

Answer (score 1):

The llply function calls "foreach" under the hood.  Foreach uses "parant.frame()" to determine the environment to evaluate.  What is the parant.frame in llply's case?  It is the llply's function environment, which doesn't have factor defined.

Instead of using llply, why not use foreach directly?

```
library(plyr)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

workers <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(workers,cores=2)

factor=1
foreach(x=1:2) %dopar% {factor*x}
```

Note, you don't even need the .export parameter, since it automatically does so in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem here is not so much the environment of evaluation but what environment `foreach` uses to find the variables that should get exported. The problem goes away if one uses a variable name that is not used in `base`, let's say `a` instead of `factor`. I know that I can directly use `foreach` (like you did and I do mostly nowadays) and that the error then goes away. But back in 2013 I was a heavy `plyr` user and this error puzzled me quite a lot. So, I wanted to solve this out of curiosity.