# Error using using parallel plyr and data.table in R: Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "invalid subscript type 'list'"

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, data.table, plyr

I am trying to use the `data.table` package along with `plyr` to do some parallel computation in R,and I am getting unexpected behavior. I am using windows 7.

I have created the following function that produces a freqency table using `data.table`

```
 t_dt_test <- function(x){ 
    #creates a 1-d frequency table for x
    dt <- data.table(x)
    dt[, j = list(freq = .N), by = x] 
}
```

Create some test data

```
 test <- list(letters[1:3],letters[1:3],letters[1:3])
```

This works fine using `llply` with `.parallel = FALSE`

```
 llply(test, t_dt_test, .parallel = FALSE)
     [[1]]
   x freq
1: a    1
2: b    1
3: c    1
```

Buyt if I try it in parrallel it does not work

```
library(doParallel)
nodes <- detectCores()
cl <-makeCluster(nodes)


llply(test, t_dt_test, .parallel = TRUE ,.paropts = list( .packages = 'data.table'))
```

Returns this

```
Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "invalid subscript type 'list'"
```

It seems that the `[.data.table` is not being passed to the nodes as I would expect.

I tried changing the function to

```
 t_dt_test <- function(x){ 
        #creates a 1-d frequency table for x
        dt <- data.table(x)
        data.table:::`[.data.table`(x = dt,  j = list(freq = .N), by = x)
    }
```

but still gets the same error.

A similar question was asked here: [Strange environment behavior in parallel plyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840167/strange-environment-behavior-in-parallel-plyr) but got no answers

Any suggestions?

Comment: data.table doesn't mix well with parallel processing. I assume you can't really assign by reference in parallel.

Comment: Could you explain why this might be?

Comment: Having a similar problem... Using doSNOW and data.table. This is a shame since data.table speeds things up so well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a very small amount of extra work you can paralellize this using the `foreach` package.

Try this:

```
library(data.table)

t_dt_test <- function(x){ 
  dt <- data.table(x)
  dt[, j = list(freq = .N), by = x] 
}

test <- list(letters[1:3],letters[1:3],letters[1:3])
```

Use `foreach()` in sequential compute mode first, to ensure you have the correct syntax. Since the `foreach()` loop takes care  of splitting and combining, `llply()` is no longer used:

```
library(foreach)
foreach(i = seq_along(test), .combine = c) %do% {
  list(
    t_dt_test(test[[i]])
  )
}
```

To run this in parallel, you only have to change `%do%` to `%dopar` and remember to add `data.table` to the package list:

```
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(detectCores())
foreach(i = seq_along(test), .combine = c, .packages = "data.table") %dopar% {
  list(
    t_dt_test(test[[i]])
  )
}
```

The results are as expected:

```
[[1]]
   x freq
1: a    1
2: b    1
3: c    1

[[2]]
   x freq
1: a    1
2: b    1
3: c    1

[[3]]
   x freq
1: a    1
2: b    1
3: c    1
```